# When a user was last online

Tags: php, cookies

I have a database table to keep a log of user activity. It stores their latest activity on the site via my login check script at the top of each page, this updates their activity time to NOW whenever they browse a new page. Then when they log out it puts NOW into their 'last online time'. This way I can produce a 'who's online now' list on the site, and also when someone logs in again I can tell them about new posts and activity since they were last online by checking the last online time stored.

However, if someone doesn't log out which I've noticed a few people doing, their last online time doesn't get updated and the new activity since last visit won't work properly.

I'm working in php and session data, no cookies as yet, tho I want to code a 'keep me logged in' feature which will have to use cookies, and I'm thinking they may help.

I'm thinking I could maybe update a cookie on each page with their latest activity time, then later do a check to see if the time was more than a few hours ago or something like that. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Create a column for last seen, update the timestamp that's all you need

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have already as my 'last online', as well as my recent activity that gets updated page by page, but how do I keep last online up to date if they don't log out? As when you log in again your  recent activity gets updated to now so is no good for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a last-online cookie (hashed with a secret key to prevent forgery), and update it every time someone views a page. You were on the right track.

I assume the problem is that users are just closing their browser tabs instead of logging out, and it's not triggering the script that changes the timestamp in the DB? Or is it that users are just leaving the tab open for untold amounts of time?

Regardless, checking the cookie should take care of this feature for you (Don't forget to hash it with a secret key though! Laziness is the killer of security.)

Comment: Yes people just close their browser thus not triggering the right scrip. and thanks for the security tip! I have been a bit lazy on that so far. eek. I'll see how I get on with a cookie, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the last online feature just put a time and date stamp into a database and load that into a 'last seen' list. Then for keep me logged in part save the md5 hash of there password into cookies and check for that on login (using javascript).